# Create a BindableProperty with the newest version (not deprecated)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to update my deprecated code, here it is :

```
public static readonly BindableProperty CompletedProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached<EntryCompletedBehavior, Command>(
               bindable => EntryCompletedBehavior.GetCompleted(bindable), /* staticgetter */
               null, /* default value */
               BindingMode.OneWay, /* defaultBindingMode */
               null, /* validateValue */
               (b, o, n) => EntryCompletedBehavior.OnCompletedChanged(b, o, n), /* PropertyChanged */
               null, /* PropertyChanging */
               null); /* CoerceValue */
```

But I'm not sure what to put in PropertyName, returnType, declaringType and PropertyChanged. I found this code here [http://pause.coffee/blog/...](http://pause.coffee/blog/xamarin-forms-ii-custom-attached-properties-and-behaviors/) , currently the following code does'nt work :  :

```
public static readonly BindableProperty CompletedProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
               "Completed", /* string PropertyName */
               typeof(Command), /* Type returnType */
               typeof(Command), /* Type declaringType */

               null, /* default value */
               BindingMode.OneWay,
               null,
               (b, o, n) => EntryCompletedBehavior.OnCompletedChanged(b, o, n),
               null,
               null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Bill Reiss ;-)

The following code is working :

```
public static readonly BindableProperty CompletedProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
                "Completed", /* string PropertyName */
                typeof(Command), /* Type returnType */
                typeof(Entry), /* Type declaringType */
                null, /* default value */
                BindingMode.OneWay, /* defaultBindingMode */
                propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) => {
                    EntryCompletedBehavior.OnCompletedChanged(bindable, (Command)oldValue, (Command)newValue);
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a GitHub link to when Charles Petzold updated his samples to use a non-generic BindableProperty, if you look at the before and after it should help you.

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-book-preview-2/commit/1786d2062eeee856b6031a0e48378d58b7c9e222

Comment: FWIW: Some links. Not directly relevant, but when I saw that link, it made me wonder where link was to the [final version of the book](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/) and its samples and [toolkit library](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-book-samples/tree/master/Libraries/Xamarin.FormsBook.Toolkit).